# Push Notifications with SSE

Tags: javascript, php, push-notification, server-sent-events

I am writing a simple game using JS and PHP. The game has one team lead and 5 other members in a group. I want a push notification to be sent to the 5 members browser whenever the team lead makes a decision by clicking a button on his own browser. So, far, I have come up with **Option 1**

**Option 1 :**
*Team Lead clicks button -> JS updates event in DB table via ajax -> Server php program polls table every x secs -> if new updates found, send notification to members via SSE*

As the team lead makes decisions sparingly, I just thought that polling the table every x secs can be a waste of resources. I want to know whether **Option 2** will work

**Option 2 :**
*Team Lead clicks button -> JS posts (HTML POST) event to Server php program -> Server php program sends notification to members via SSE*

Will this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: yes, Option 2 is better than option 1. It will work.

Comment: Thanks. I will test it out and post my results.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.  If you're writing in javascript and php, it's often a good idea to add those tags to your question to help people find it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Added the tags.

Comment: I tried using Option 2 but it does not seem to work and probably rightly so. The member client opens connection to the Server every Y secs, determined by the "retry" parameter in the Server php program. However, the button click on the from the Team Lead client is arbitrary. So, I do not see how Option 2 will work.